# Array from PHP to Javascript (Using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some problems trying to redraw some markers (on google maps) from a database, use the form jquery

Index.html:

```
var map;
var datos;

function updateLocations(){ 
  var post= $.post('php/getLoc.php',{table: "Auto"), function f(data){
  datos =[]; //clear array with the last positions
  datos = data; 
  drawAutos(datos); }); }
```

php/getLoc.php:

```
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("database") or die ('could not select db');
  $autos= "SELECT * FROM autos ORDER BY auto_id ASC";   
  $result=mysql_query($autos) or die('query fail'.mysql_error());
  $datos= array();
  while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $datos[] = array(
       0=>$row['taxi_id'],
       1=>$row['lat'],
       2=>$row['lng'],
       3=>$row['availability']);}   
  $out = array_values($datos);
  var_dump(json_encode($out));
  mysql_free_result($result);
  mysql_close($link);
```

The query is correct, but I get the information otherwise. there is a way to remove the **string () ""** (see picture), I have tried using $.parseJSON(data) and $.getJSON(data) but not work for me =(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo json_encode($out);` instead of `var_dump($out);`. Also, `mysql` is depreciated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` or something else. The Object Oriented Approach will save you time. Also, you can `$mysqli_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of making your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is working now :), thanks to PHPglue, I use

PHP File:

```
echo json_encode($out)
```

I also do in Index File:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
drawAutos(obj);
```